# `newline' unexpected when run shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sqlplus

Im new to unix command. I would like to execute jasper file P70152R1 and pass busDt param to that file. 
Currently hit this error >>> **line 51: syntax error at line 53: `newline' unexpected**

Can anyone help me to check my shell script.

Below is my script:

```
echo "*********************************************************"
echo "*         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     *"
echo "*********************************************************"
echo
echo "*********************************************************************************"
echo "*                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                  *"
echo "*                            UP                             *"
echo "*     P700152R1 - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA REPORT            *"
echo "*     P700152R2 - BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB REPORT        *"
echo "*     P700152R3 - CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC REPORT            *"
echo "*                           (JP700152)                          *"
echo "*                        FREQUENCY : DAILY                          *"
echo ****************************************************************************"
echo
cd $MAIN/CWJCL/ACQ
export JCL=$MAIN/CWJCL/ACQ
export PRM=$MAIN/CWPRM/ACQ:$MAIN/CWPRM/CMN
export JAS=$MAIN/CWRPT/ACQ
export rptDir=$MAIN/ACQ/DAILYRPT
export LOG=$MAIN/CWLOG/ACQ

echo "Start Time and Date : \c" &&date
echo
JP70152=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
$JCL/strtJob $JP70152 JP70152

# Classpath
. $JCL/SETENV
#export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PRM:$LIB/acq-1.0.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PRM:"$MAIN/CWLIB/classes/acq"

# Get Business Date
echo "set heading off;" > $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo "spool $LOG/date.log;" >> $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=CCPS;" >> $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo "SELECT 'CURRENT-BUSS-DATE:'||F9_AP008_BUS_DT FROM AP008;" >> $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo "spool off;" >> $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo "EXIT;" >> $LOG/busDtSel.sql
echo
$JCL/CONNAM.sh $LOG/busDtSel.sql $LOG/sel_day
a=$?
if [ ! $a -eq 0 ]
then
   return $a
fi

tmpDt=`grep CURRENT-BUSS-DATE $LOG/date.log`
busDt=${tmpDt##*:}

# run program.
yyyymmdd=`date +%Y%m%d`
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator -Ttxt -J$JAS/P70152R1.jasper -DACQ -O$rptDir/P70152R1.rpt -P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>
##########$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator -Ttxt -J$JAS/P70152R2.jasper -DACQ -O$rptDir/P70152R2.rpt -P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>
##########$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator -Ttxt -J$JAS/P70152R3.jasper -DACQ -O$rptDir/P70152R3.rpt -P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>
a=$?
echo $a
if [ ! $a -eq 0 ]
then
   return $a
fi
echo
echo
echo
$JCL/endJob $JP70152 JP70152
echo "End Time and Date : \c" &&date
echo
return $a
```

Really appreciate your help. Thanks id advance !

Comment: If this is a bash script, the `>` at the end of the line might throw it off. Maybe you have to edit the script by replacing `-P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>`?

Comment: This would have helped: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hi @RolandWeber. It's worked. Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2):

The `<` and `>` characters have a special meaning in bash. You used them in

```
echo "set heading off;" > $LOG/busDtSel.sql
```

to redirect the output of the echo to `$LOG/busDtSel.sql`.

In your line 53, you do:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator options -P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>
```

That means that the last argument for the `JRGenerator` is `-P`, that the stdin comes from the file `BUS-DATE:$busDt` and that stdout goes to, ehm, nothing. There is a new-line. That is unexpected for bash, because it expected a destination for stdout. Hence the error message.

The solution is to use quotes:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator options "-P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>"
```

There are other issues in your script as well; for example: there is a line with:

```
echo ************************************"
```

which should obviously  be:

```
echo "************************************"
```

I think that this might be a mistake in putting the script in the question, because this generates a different error message for me.

Comment: Yes it's working now ! Thank you so much for your explaination ! And second issue, yes I missed out the ". Hihi. Thanks ! :))

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `"` at the beginning of a line and therefore screws up everything:

```
        echo "*********************************************************************************"
        echo "*                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                  *"
        echo "*                            UP                             *"
        echo "*     P700152R1 - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA REPORT            *"
        echo "*     P700152R2 - BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB REPORT        *"
        echo "*     P700152R3 - CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC REPORT            *"
        echo "*                           (JP700152)                          *"
        echo "*                        FREQUENCY : DAILY                          *"
HERE -> echo ****************************************************************************"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are using `>` operator at the end of your java command. Better use a escape sequence to overcome this issue. See below correct expression.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator -Ttxt -J$JAS/P70152R1.jasper -DACQ -O$rptDir/P70152R1.rpt -P\<BUS-DATE:$busDt\>
```

or, you can try like below as Ljm provided in his answer:-

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java my.com.eprotea.report.JRGenerator -Ttxt -J$JAS/P70152R1.jasper -DACQ -O$rptDir/P70152R1.rpt "-P<BUS-DATE:$busDt>"
```

Comment: Or the syntax of the argument to the `-P` switch really is like that and it just needs to be escaped by either enclosing in `'`, or `"`; or escaping with backslash (`\>`). Don’t forget, there’s still another `<` that has a special meaning as well.

Comment: @dulange, you are correct, I just overlooked the first `<`. Thanks :-). I have corrected the answer.